# How to break out of an (asyncio) websocket fetch loop that doesn't have any incoming messages?

Tags: websocket, python-asyncio

This code prints all messages from a websocket connection:

```py
class OrderStreamer:
    def __init__(ᬑ):
        ᬑ.terminate_flag = False

        # worker thread to receive data stream
        ᬑ.worker_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=ᬑ.worker_thread_func,
            daemon=True
            )

    def start_streaming(ᬑ, from_scheduler = False):
        ᬑ.worker_thread.start()


    def terminate(ᬑ):
        ᬑ.terminate_flag = True


    def worker_thread_func(ᬑ):
        asyncio.run(ᬑ.aio_func())  # blocks


    async def aio_func(ᬑ):
        async with \
                aiohttp.ClientSession() as session, \
                session.ws_connect(streams_url) as wsock, \
                anyio.create_task_group() as tg:

            async for msg in wsock:
                print(msg.data)

                if ᬑ.terminate_flag:
                    await wsock.close()
```

The problem is that if no messages arrive, the loop never gets the chance to check `terminate_flag` and never exits.

I tried creating an external reference to the runloop and websocket:

```
        async with \
                aiohttp.ClientSession() as session, \
                session.ws_connect(streams_url) as wsock, \
                anyio.create_task_group() as tg:

            ᬑ.wsock = wsock
            ᬑ.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

... and modifying my terminate function:

```
    def terminate(ᬑ):
        # ᬑ.loop.stop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(ᬑ.loop)

        async def kill():
            await ᬑ.wsock.close()

        asyncio.run(kill())
```

... but it does not work.

I can't afford to rearchitect my entire application to use asyncio at this point in time.

How to break out of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `asyncio.wait_for` or `asyncio.wait` and call `wsock.__anext__()` directly instead of using `async for` loop.

The loop with `asyncio.wait` should look something like this:

```py
next_message = asyncio.create_task(wsock.__anext__())

while not self.terminate_flag:
    await asyncio.wait([next_message], timeout=SOME_TIMEOUT,)
    if next_message.done():
        try:
            msg = next_message.result()
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            break
        else:
            print(msg.data)
            next_message = asyncio.create_task(wsock.__anext__())
```

`SOME_TIMEOUT` should be replaced with the amount of seconds you want to wait continuously for the next incoming message

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) is the documentation for `asyncio.wait`

P.S. I replaced `ᬑ` with `self`, but I hope you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Note that to read data you should not create a new task as mentioned [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#reading-from-the-same-task-in-websockets):

> Reading from the WebSocket (await ws.receive()) must only be done inside the request handler task;

You can simply use timeout.

```
async def handler(request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()  # or web.WebSocketResponse(receive_timeout=5)
    await ws.prepare(request)
    while True:
        try:
            msg = await ws.receive(timeout=5)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print('TimeoutError')
            if your_terminate_flag is True:
                break
```

`aiohttp/web_protocol.py/_handle_request()` will dump errors if you don't write try/except or don't catch the right exception. Try testing `except Exception as err:` or check its source code.